# Get the url of a page template without using the page slug and ID

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls, page-template, links

Can I get the url of the page "page-template-contactus.php" using "template-contactus" only?

Comment: Hi monica, you mean something like `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/myTheme/page-template-contactus.php` ?

Comment: This should be the url "http://localhost/?page_id=78", but I can't get it without using the slug or ID (in code). Is it possible to get the ID using the basename?

Comment: and can you please specify where do you need to get this?in a loop? your theme's function? homepage? etc.

Comment: In another page template.. Not in a loop. I just need a link to that page template.

Comment: I just created a page for a custom post type, and there is a "Leave a review" button. I need to put the link there. (to "page-template-leavereview.php).

Comment: Why can't you use slug, id or direct link? You must provide something to fetch the URL though.

Comment: Because I get the slug/id/direct link when I create that page, but what if another person use this code and create a page called differently?

Comment: Then he/she must update the code. You can't get the URL to a page by using template name,because there might be a hundred of pages made using that particular template. You either need the page ID, Name, Or slug.